# why am I getting http status code 0 during unit test in laravel 10?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing

I'm trying to make a unit test for a new model I'm creating in my Laravel 10 project. But in my unit test, I'm getting the error "http status code '0' is not valid." why is that? I've been struggling with this for days now. can anyone point me to the right direction? any help is appreciated.

this is the unit test I'm trying to run:

`CulinaryTest.php`

```
class CulinaryTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase, WithFaker;

    public function test_add_comment(): void
    {
        $culinary = Culinary::whereNotNull('published_date')->first();
        
        $inputData = [
            'body' => fake()->sentence(),
            'commentId' => 'c1',
            'commentableType' => 'culinary',
            'commentableId' => $culinary->id,
        ];
        // dd($inputData);
        $response = $this->post(route('v1.culinary.add-comment',['culinary'=>$culinary->id]),
        $inputData, $this->headers);
        // dd($response);
        $response->dd();
        
        $response->assertCreated();
        $response->assertJsonStructure([
            'data'=>[
                'id','entity','attributes'=>[
                    'userId','commentableType','commentableId'
                ]
            ]
        ]);
        $this->assertDatabaseHas('comments',[
            'commentable_type'=>'culinary',
            'commentable_id'=>$culinary->id,
            'user_id'=>$this->user->id,
        ]);
        $this->assertNotEquals($culinary->total_comments,
        Culinary::where('id',$culinary->id)->first()->total_comments);

        # tes user melakukan like culinary sendiri
        $user = $culinary->user;
        $this->actingAs($user);

        $response = $this->postJson(route('v1.culinary.add-comment',['culinary'=>$culinary->id]),
        [],$this->headers);
        
        $response->assertForbidden();
    }
    // end public function test_add_comment
}
```

and these are my code:

`migrations/..create_comments_table.php`

```
        Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('body');
            $table->enum('commentable_type', ['paradise', 'culinary', 'guide', 'tour_package']);
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('commentable_id');
            $table->string('comment_id')->default('c1');
            $table->string('parent_id')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            // foreign key ke tabel `users`
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

`Models/Comment.php`

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function commentable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

`Models/Culinary.php`

```
class Culinary extends Model
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable');
    }
}
```

`CommentResource.php`

```
    public function toArray(Request $request): array
    {
        $this->user;

        $response = [
            'id'=>$this->id,
            'entity'=>'comments',
            'attributes'=>[
                'userId'=>$this->user_id,
                'commentId'=>$this->comment_id,
                'parentId'=>$this->parent_id,
                'body'=>$this->body,
                'commentableType'=>$this->commentable_type,
                'commentableId'=>$this->commentable_id
            ]
        ];
```

`CommentRepository.php`

```
class CommentRepository implements CommentInterface
{
    public function create($content)
    {
        try{
            return DB::transaction(function () use ($content) {
                $user = auth()->user();
                # panggil relasi comments dari model content
                return $content->comments()->create(['user_id'=>$user->id]);
            });

        }catch (Exception $error){
            $message = $error->getMessage() ?? "INSERT_ERR";
            $code = (int)$error->getCode();

            /**
             * jika kode tidak umum, maka perlu di notif ke slack agar dapat
             * di perbaiki lebih lanjut
             */
            if($code>600){
                $code = 500;

                # error tidak biasa lebih baik di notif ke slack agar jelas
                Log::critical("CommentRepository::create",[
                    'userLogin'=>auth()->user(),
                    'data'=>$content,
                    'errorExceptionCode'=>$error->getCode(),
                    'errorException'=>$error->getMessage()
                ]);
            }

            return response()->json(['status' => 'ERR', 'message' => $message], $code);
            // return response()->json(['errors' => $error], 500);
        }
    }
}
```

`CommentController.php`

```
    public function store(StoreCommentRequest $request)
    {
        $response = $this->commentRepo->create($request->input());

        if(!$response instanceof \App\Models\Comment){
            return $response;
        }

        return (new CommentResource($response))->response()->setStatusCode(201);
    }
```

`StoreCommentRequest.php`

```
class StoreCommentRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     */
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return $this->user()->can('create', Comment::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule|array|string>
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'userId' => ['required','exists:users,id'],
            'body' => ['required'],
            'commentId' => ['nullable'],
            'parentId' => ['nullable'],
            'commentableType' => ['required'],
            'commentableId' => ['required'],
        ];
    }

    protected function passedValidation(): void
    {
        $data = $this->validated();
        $data['user_id'] = $this->userId??null;
        $data['comment_id'] = $this->commentId??null;
        $data['parent_id'] = $this->parentId??null;
        $data['commentable_type'] = $this->commentableType??null;
        $data['commentable_id'] = $this->commentableId??null;
        $data = Arr::except($data,['userId', 'commentId', 'parentId', 'commentableType', 'commentableId']);
        $this->replace($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which exact line of your test is falling? You do have 2 HTTP tests when you should only have one